# Controlling the action of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start C#

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start function on my client application (written in c#) to call a URL and perform the corresponding action.

```
string targetURL = "someurl";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);
```

Running the URL makes certain changes on the server and gives a PLAIN_TEXT response.
Now the thing is on calling this function it opens the web browser and shows that the `targetURL` has been called.
Is there any way this could be stopped?

What I mean is that I want the changes to take place but the browser shouldn't open.
The changes should be made though.

Comment: create a ProcessStartInfo object and pass it to the process, there is a option for that.

Comment: Is it a http request?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(targetURL); Process.Start(sInfo);

Comment: @Grzenio yes its a http request

Comment: I think there should be a better way to acheive what you want.. though we don't exactly *know* what you need. `Process.Start(url)` will start the default browser... I guess that does something? But anyways if you want to do it behind the back use: `ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow` and `ProcessStartInfo.NoShellExec` but a simple `HttpRequest` could also do the trick, parhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("someurl");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content. 
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you actually want to make a http request and use the text that was returned as a response. If this is the case, you should use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of starting a process.

Example from MSDN:

```
  // Create a New HttpClient object.
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions 
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below 
     // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }  
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }

  // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient object 
  // when done using it, so the app doesn't leak resources
  client.Dispose(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. The GetAsync method will perform a GET request. There are also methods for POST, PUT, and DELETE.

```
// Call the GetWorkflow web-method.
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    string myUrl = "http://someurl";
    var response = client.GetAsync(myUrl).Result;
}
```

You can also look into the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (e.g. [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), or [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Plenty of examples of both of these on the net.